# I am getting a NameError: name 'n' is not defined

Tags: python, function

This function asks the name

```
def printName():
   print("Enter your name: ")
   n=input()
printName()
```

The if statement checks if n is equal to Python

```
if n=="Python":
   print("Welcome")
else:
   print("Try again")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is only defined inside the function. This should work:

```
def printName():
   print("Enter your name: ")
   n=input()
   if n=='Python':
     ...
```

Alternatively you can also do:

```
def printName():
       print("Enter your name: ")
       n=input()
       return n

n = printName()
# now you can use n
```